# javascript: Access object properties through variable

Tags: javascript

I want to access a Javascript Object dynamicly.

Example:

```
example: { 
    name: "dev.pus", 
    year: 2012, 
    os: "linux" 
}
```

This isn't anything new. Now you normaly can access properties of the "example" with:

```
console.log(example.name);
// or
console.log(example.year);
```

But what is if I want to take the attribute dynamicly?
For example, another var (lets assume the user sets it) should decide which property we want:

```
var = "name";
console.log(example.var); // error
console.log(example[var]); // error
```

What is the way to go?

Comment: `example[variable]` should work. You're just choosing the worst name in the history of variable names... `var` is a reserved keyword in Javascript.

Comment: Btw, don't replace var by package, or new or function :)

Answer (score 3):

Your example should work if you'll change your variable name (var is reserved).

```
var key = 'name';
console.log(example[key]);
```

You can also iterate over your object to get all keys:

```
for (var item in example){
    if (example.hasOwnProperty(item)){
      console.log(example[item]);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bC9XJ/

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post. To the beginning I thought this was a Javascript issue but now this seems to be related with jquery. Maybe you remember the pattern from the other thread ;)